# how to convert a string date to date format in oracle10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

My date value is stored as `varchar2` and the value is `15/August/2009,4:30 PM`, how to convert this to a proper date format like `DD-MM-YYYY`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can convert a string to a DATE using the TO_DATE function, then reformat the date as another string using TO_CHAR, i.e.:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE('15/August/2009,4:30 PM'
                ,'DD/Month/YYYY,HH:MI AM')
       ,'DD-MM-YYYY')
FROM DUAL;

15-08-2009
```

For example, if your table name is MYTABLE and the varchar2 column is MYDATESTRING:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE(MYDATESTRING
                ,'DD/Month/YYYY,HH:MI AM')
       ,'DD-MM-YYYY')
FROM MYTABLE;
```

Comment: Thank you. I some how managed to get this result using substring function. But your answer is more simple than than i used. Thank you very much. My sql statement is select to_date(substr(CRM_ACC_DATE_TIME,1,instr(CRM_ACC_DATE_TIME,',')-1),'dd-mm-yyyy') from crm_claim_int_details_view;

Comment: Yep, there's usually more than one way to skin a cat :)

Answer (score 13):

You need to use the `TO_DATE` function.

```
SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/2004', 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: i am getting this error msg  ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
ORA-02063: preceding line from GENCONAIMSUAT
01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
*Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
           incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
           required by the format model.
*Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
           elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.