# SQL query for date format for CLOB field is not working

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I am using the below query to get the date in the format 'DD-MM-YYYY' from a CLOB field from ORACLE Toad.

```
 Select ID, NVL(TO_CHAR(xmltype(XML_RAW).extract('//ROWSET//ROW//MJR_V//MJR_V_ROW//EARLIEST_ACCEPT_DATE/text()').getStringVal(), 'DD-MM-YYYY'),'') 
 AS Dateformat from table1 where ID = 102
```

It thorws error:

```
ORA:01722: Invalid number
```

But if I use the above query direct DB columns (NOT CLOB FIELDS) then it executes fine.

```
 Select ID, NVL(TO_CHAR(Start_Date, 'DD-MM-YYYY'),'') 
 AS Dateformat from table1 where   ID = 102
```

Please let me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't run [`to_char`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) on varchar2

[`to_char`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) function gets a date (or a number) as an argument and converts it to a varchar2.
If you use it on a varchar2, then oracle implicitly converts the string to a date according to [`NLS_DATE_FORMAT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm)

So you sould probably do something like [this:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366522/how-to-convert-a-string-date-to-date-format-in-oracle10g)

Comment: What did you put as your format in the `to_date` function ? how does `EARLIEST_ACCEPT_DATE` look like in the XML ?