# How to Convert character to date format in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have data like :

```
MAR-16
APR-17
MAR-18
JUN-16
```

I want to sort it in ascending order based on date,but as the data is in character , I am not sure how to sort them based on date .
Expected output is :

```
MAR-16
JUN-16
APR-17
MAR-18
```

Can someone please help .

Comment: order by to_date('01-' || column_name,'DD-MON-YY') asc;

Comment: Hi, what have you tried? There are no shortages of questions like this.  Here is an example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366522/how-to-convert-a-string-date-to-date-format-in-oracle10g

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert a string date to date format in oracle10g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366522/how-to-convert-a-string-date-to-date-format-in-oracle10g)

Comment: Where should `JUN-97` be shown? Before `MAR-16` or after it?

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
order by to_date(col, 'MON-YY')
```

But you should fix the column so it has a correct data type.

Comment: Wouldn't that, actually, be MON-DD, rather than MON-YY? True, the OP didn't specify whether "MAR-16" represents March 16th or March 2016, but I suspect that numeric part of those values is a DAY, not a year. Not your mistake, @Gordon, I'm just saying.

Comment: @Littlefoot . . . Look at the desired ordering.  It looks like a year, not a day.

Comment: On a second thought, yes - you're most probably right. Which makes me wrong. Huh, two wrongs don't make right, but two Wrights made an airplane.